# mounting minix filesystem on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, minix

How can I mount a Minix filesystem in Ubuntu?
I'm trying to do

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=1024 -t minix B30M biggy/
```

and I get

mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Thanks!

Comment: ... and when you do `dmesg | tail` as the error suggests, is there anything minix related?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you need the offset? Thats an unusual option to use, usually a filesystem will start at the beginning of the file.

Try 

`sudo mount -o loop -t minix B30M biggy/`

On the other hand, if you do require the offset, are you sure that's the right number? Try looking through the file for a minix filesystem magic number.

This should identify any possible Minix filesystems

`od -Ad -x B30M | grep 0410`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command to find it:

```
dmesg | grep minix
```

Which gives an output like:

```
sdb1: <minix: sdb5 sdb6 sdb7>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to mount a Minux3 file system? As I recall, only Minix2 file systems are supported by Linux.

Comment: no, minix2 :D have you done this before?